# Javascript Regex - | (OR) Operator return only the first match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression `/(co|com)/gi` to match `com` or `co` depending on whichever is present.

But, `'com'.match(/(co|com)/gi)` returns only `["co"]`?

Any idea why? Shouldn't it to a greedy match instead of returning the first match? How do I make to return `com` ?

Comment: swapping `'com'.match(/(com|co)/gi` returns `com` as I expected, but is there a way without swapping the match orders?

Comment: Well, making in the `m` optional would also work in this case. I.e. `/com?/gi`.  But this is just how regex works. If finds `co`, and then it searches for the next match that's co or com.

Comment: from the duplicate question, I found a fix: using `/(co|com)\b/gi` actually returns what I wanted. Just FYI.

Comment: Indeed, adding a wordboundary `\b` after it has that effect. As long you're not looking for "com" in "comment" anyway.

Comment: that's correct. I don't want it to match `comment`. :)